# Semange fcontext (/.*)? explanation

Tags: linux, selinux

I have a question in regards to a semanage command,

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t 'var/Norway(/.*)?'
```

What does (/.*)? exactly do, I know it changes the file type, but not sure about the specific details.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`(/.*)?` is a regular expression. It means the `semanage` command will apply to the path:

```
/var/Norway
```

but also to sub directories and files in there like

```
/var/Norway/foo.txt
/var/Norway/bar/foo.txt
...
```

but it will not apply to a path like:

```
/var/Norway_Foo
```